# Calculate the possibility of drawing at least once 1 white ball exactly after repeating the experiment 4 times.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions

The exercise's text is:

A box has 3 black balls and one white ball. And we have a coin black from a side and white from the other side.

We throw the coin, if it fell on the white side we add 1 white ball to the box. If fell on the black side, we add 1 black ball to the box. Then we draw 3 balls all at once from the box.

We call "E1": We draw only 1 white ball from all the 3 balls we usually draw.

- We repeat the whole experiment four times and with the same rules.

2. Calculate the possibility of drawing once at least 1 white ball exactly(We call this incident "A")

Now, the book solved it like this:

$P(A) = 1 - P(\overline{E1})^4$

But I don't understand why. How the possibility of A is the opposite of $\overline{E1}$? As I understand it, $\overline{E1}$ is drawing any white ball then the opposite of it is drawing 1 ball only...right? If this is the case then why the heck we made all this extra steps? Why can't we just write $P(A) = P(E1)^4$? And why is there a power of 4 here? Why we don't multiply it as example?

Also, if we repeated the experiment four times and with the same rules. Doesn't that mean the number of black and white balls will change because depending on the side of the coin we would add a black/white ball to the box? Doesn't that affect the whole experiment?

I don't understand.

Comment: What does "at least one white ball exactly" mean?

Comment: @lulu It's "At least once, 1 white ball exactly" it means that at least once, you would draw only 1 white ball. Like 1 white ball and no more of the white balls.

Comment: What?  Am I drawing the three balls more than once?  I think you need to rewrite the question.  You define $E_1$ to be "We draw 1 ball only from all the three balls" which makes no sense.

Comment: @lulu Oops. Sorry for that. I meant "We draw only 1 white ball from all the three balls we usually draw"

Comment: So, with these edits, the proposed formula is  correct, yes?  The only way to fail to see $E_1$ at least once in four independent trials is to see $\overline {E_1}$ four times in a row,  The probability of that complimentary event is the product $P\left(\overline {E_1}\right)^4$,

Comment: @lulu I still don't understand.

Comment: What don't you understand?  Forget the coin and the balls.  This is a simple binomial process (albeit dressed up in cumbersome terms).  For each trial the probability of success is $p$, independent  of all the other trials.  Thus the probability of failure is $1-p$  Thus the probability of failing four times in a row is $(1-p)^4$.  Thus the probability of at least one success in four trials is $1-(1-p)^4$.  Of course, you still need to compute $p$, but that is not difficult,

Comment: @lulu Oh, I understood that. What I don't understand is how the number of black and white balls don't change even though we throw the coin four times. Shouldn't that change the whole calculations because the number of white balls(And balls overall) has changed?

Comment: I don't understand.  I thought the trials were identical and independent.  As a result, the probability of success for each is the same (again, independent of all the other trials).